# Get time from remote time server in R

Tags: r, time

How can the current timestamp be queried from a remote server (e.g., NIST, windows time server) using R?

I'm guessing it is possible to obtain time using NIST Internet Time Service (https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/services/internet-time-service-its), but unsure how this would be done.

Comment: I suggest the *"using R"* part is not truly the key here. If you can find an HTTP endpoint, then using `httr::GET` (or `::POST`) will be straight-forward.

Comment: good point. this works: `httr::GET("http://time.gov/")$date`

Comment: note that this method only reads data from the HTTP date header; not from the NIST time server directly. e.g., this produces same result: `httr::GET("http://www.google.com/")$date`